# OverlayLibrary Popovers Glitching With Focusable Element

Tags: lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console, lightning-overlaylibrary

I created a component that displays a list of related records. When the user hovers over a record, a popover is opened showing a preview of the record using the lightning:overlayLibrary component. The popovers auto closes if you mouse over another record. It all works great except if I add a focusable element (e.g. a button to close the popover). For some reason this causes the window to scroll to the top if I move my mouse over 2-3 records. The popovers open/close correctly but the user will be randomly taken back to the top of the page if they've scrolled down.

I don't set the focus at all in my code so I don't know why this is happening.

The lightning design system documentation around popovers even states a focusable element is required.

Has anyone else run into this before?

*Update*
Here's the snippet of code for showing/hiding the popovers:

```
showPopoverHelper : function(component, event){
    this.hidePopoverHelper(component, event); // close any open popovers
// get content for popover
    var index = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-index').value;
    var suggestedArticles = component.get('v.suggestedArticles');
    var attributes = {"article": suggestedArticles[index]};

    $A.createComponent('c:ArticlePreview', attributes, function(newComp, status, errorMessage){
        if(status === "SUCCESS"){
            component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
                body: newComp,
                referenceSelector: '#' + event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('id').value,
                cssClass: "slds-popover,cKnowledgeOne",
            }).then(function (overlay) {
                var popoverList = component.get('v.popoverInstance');
                popoverList.push(overlay); // add popover instance to array
                component.set('v.popoverInstance', popoverList);
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log('error: ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
},

hidePopoverHelper : function(component, event){
    var popoverList = component.get('v.popoverInstance');

    if(popoverList != null){
        for(var index in popoverList){ // close all popovers in array
            var popover = popoverList[index];
            if(popover != null){
                popover.close();
            }
        }
    }

    clearTimeout(component.get('v.hoverTimer'));
    component.set('v.hoverTimer', null);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in the way the overlay library closes popovers. The issue disappears if you use hide() instead of close() as close() destroys the popover and randomly returns focus to the top of the screen. Hide does not have this issue

Answer (score 1):

We had quite similar issue with popovers.

---

Background:

Had a attribute to store the reference of overlay:

```
<aura:attribute name="overlay" type="Aura.Component[]" />
```

overlay is set in the promise:

```
component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
    // pop over body
}).then(function (overlay) {
    component.set('v.overlay',overlay);
}
```

Did following to close the popover:

```
var overlay = component.get("v.overlay")[0];
overlay.close();
```

---

Took sometime to find that `overlay.close` method looked like this:

```
close(shouldReturnFocus) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this._panelInstance.close(() => {
            resolve();
        }, shouldReturnFocus);
    });
}
```

So after some trial and error the solution was to not pass `0` in the parameter. Luckily we also had added documented this:

```
// passing `0` to close is an undocumented feature about returning focus. 
// It prevents the page to scroll to the top.
overlay.close(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't sending a 0 before and, unfortunately, including a 0 didn't fix the issue

Comment: Could you share a minimal version of code which could help us in replicating the issue?

Comment: Code snippet added to original post

Comment: I am facing a issue in Overlay popover. When I hove on my <a> tag its shows the hover component but if i am trying to move to hover to component it disappear. 
For Example : If you see salesforce knowledge component and hover over an article and move to hover component it does not hide.