# setting reference selector of <lighting:OverlayLibrary> popover to a <lightning:datatable>

Tags: aura, lightning-datatable, lightning-overlaylibrary, popover, popover-position

I am trying to have a popover to display next to a button when that button is clicked in the lighting data table as shown below:[image]

As you can see, the pop over appears in the upper left hand corner instead of next to the info button.

The problem is that I can't reference the icon-button in the data table to pass it to reference selector of Overlay Library.

Below is my code. Please let me know on how I can fix this and excuse my rookie mistakes, I am new to Stack exchange and Salesforce developing.

Thank you!

**Markup:**

```
<div class="slds-grid" align = "bottom">
    <div class="slds-col slds-text-heading_large">Accounts</div>       
    <div class="slds-col " align ="right">
        Billing Groups

        <lightning:button class ="mainPopover"  iconName="utility:info"   variant="bare" onclick = "{!c.handlePopover}" />


    </div>

    <div class="slds-col" align="right" >

        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label = "Closed Accounts" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label = "Admin Info"/>
    </div> 
</div>



<div class="slds-table">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.mydata))}" >
        <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
        <lightning:datatable keyField="id"
                             data="{! v.mydata }"
                             columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                             onrowaction="{!c.handleInlinePopover}"></lightning:datatable>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.mydata)}" >
        <p>{!v.noResults}</p>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isLoading }">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading"/>
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
({
init: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchData(component);
},
handlePopover : function (component, event, helper){
    helper.mainPopover(component, event);
},

handleInlinePopover : function (component, event, helper){
 helper.inlinePopover(component, event);   

}
```

})

**Helper**

```
({
fetchData: function (component) {

    var action = component.get('c.getData');
    action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
            if(jsonData) {

                component.set('v.mycolumns', [
                    { label: 'Registration', fieldName: 'registration', type: 'text'},
                    { label: 'Type', fieldName: 'accountType', type: 'text'},
                    { label: 'Account#', fieldName: 'accountNum', type: 'text'},
                    //{ label: 'EO Visible', fieldName: 'eoVisible', type: 'boolean'},
                    { label: 'Custodian', fieldName:'custodian',type:'text'},
                    //{ label: 'Fee Schedule', fieldName:'feeSchedule', type:'text'},
                    {type: 'button-icon', initialWidth:50 ,typeAttributes: {
                     name:'inlinePopover',
                     title:'inlinePopover',
                     disabled:false,
                     class:'inlinePopover',
                     iconName: 'utility:info',
                     variant:'bare',
                     iconPosition: 'left'
                    }},
                    { label: 'SLOA on File',initialWidth:100, fieldName:'sloaOnFile', type:'boolean'},
                    { label: 'Status', initialWidth:100, fieldName:'status', type:'boolean'},
                    { label: 'Value', fieldName:'value', type:'currency'}
                ]);

                //Testing Conditional Formatting                  


                console.log('json items after parsed: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
                component.set('v.mydata', jsonData);
                component.set('v.isLoading', false );
            } else {
                component.set("v.noResults", "No records to display");
            }
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
            component.set("v.noResults", "An error occurred: No records to display");
        }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

mainPopover : function (component, event){

    $A.createComponent('c:accountListingMainPopover', {},
                       function(content, status, error) {
                           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
                                   body: content,
                                   referenceSelector:'.mainPopover',
                               });
                           } else {
                               throw new Error(error);
                           }
                       });

},

inlinePopover : function (component, event){
     var action = event.getParam('action');
    $A.createComponent('c:accountListingMainPopover', {},
                       function(content, status, error) {
                           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
                                   body: content,
                                   referenceSelector:'.'+action.class,
                               });
                               var getParam = event.getSource()
                               console.log('the class is: +++ ' + JSON.stringify(action.class));
                           } else {
                               throw new Error(error);
                           }
                       }); 




}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

come across this as I was looking at the same issue.

Found a solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234120/overlaylibrary-popovers-glitching-with-focusable-element) which is basically to use the referenceSelector to select which element the popover is appended to.

From the documentation:

```
referenceSelector   Object  The reference element to which the popover is appended. The popover is appended to the right of the reference element.
```